# reordering the letters

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider reordering the letters in the word TENNESSEE.

If the N's are placed first, how many ways are there to choose positions for them?

My solution:
n = 8    by combing the Ns into one and subtracting that from the total 9 letters
n1 = 1    because there is one N (combined)
n2 = 2    because there are two S
n3 = 4    because there is four E
n4 = 1    because there is one T

8! /  1! * 2! * 4! * 1!  =  40320 / 48  =  840

840 isnt the answer.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...any suggestions?

Comment: The numerator should have the total number of letters in the word, which is 9 and not 8.

Comment: What do you mean by  N's are placed first ? Does it mean that the string   has to start with NN or that in the $9$ spaces, we first place the two N's in any two places, and then place the rest.